# Google App Engine Launcher fails to start

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm having a problem with the Google App Engine Launcher (the GUI thingy).

I have it installed on two PCs. Both PCs have Python. On both, the launcher ran (the first time) successfully after the installation. On both, at first it failed to deploy an app I was feeding to it, apparently due to being unable to detect Python.

On my home PC, I opened preferences and manually set the path to Python. After that, the app was deployed, and the launcher has been working fine since then, never failing to start. On my work PC, I missed the opportunity to set the Python path, and the launcher fails to start. The log tells me: `ConfigParser.NoOptionError: No option 'name' in section: '0'`. I suspect this could be due to the missing Python variable.

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be any kind of config file that contains this setting for GAE. Searching the Windows registry has turned up nothing useful either. I've tried searching the site for problems with the launcher, or how to set the Python path without using GUI, but only found information on problems with *apps*, not the launcher itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google suggests:

> try to find and delete file google_appengine_projects.ini

[here](http://code.google.com/p/google-appengine-wx-launcher/issues/detail?id=6)

or

> in Google folder , you have google_appengine_projects.ini file. 
>   Delete it's [0] section.

Or just uninstall and reinstall the launcher.

If still nothing, download an IDE instead - I use [pycharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/). It's not free (there are free ones out there) but it does manage the launcher for you.

Comment: This was awesome. Deleting the .ini instantly solved the problem. It was somewhere in c:/users/username, which is why I missed it before. Can't believe I couldn't find this answer. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: It's located at C:/users/username/Google/google_appengine_projects.ini and removing the folder will lead to it's regeneration next time the launcher is run.